# Rails Models with types How to model this?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models

Business and Representative

When a business or representative signs up they are shown a list of options for "How did you hear about us?"

The discovery ways are dynamic, so the admin can add the ways in which a business or representative can discover us. For example the admin may add options 'Via Google', 'Through a Friend', 'Through another Representative' etc.. Each discovery type can either be for a business or representative or both.

How should I model the discovery_type model , What relationship it should have, I was thinking some thing along the following lines

```
Schema : 
table: discovery_types
name: string
type: string(can be one of 'business','representative', 'both')

class DiscoveryType< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :businesses
  has_many :representatives
end

class Business< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discovery_type
end

class Representative< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discovery_type
end
```

I am just not confident of this above scheme. so can anyone point out any issues and may be suggest a better way out..

Also should I add an index on any of the columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: Not Polymorphic Association, you're right - that's the opposite relationship.

This should work for the relationship you want -

```
class DiscoveryType< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :discoveries
end

class Discovery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discovery_type
end

class Business < Discovery
end

class Representative < Discovery
end
```

If you leave the `type` column in `discovery_types` Rails should automatically use it

Comment: I dont think so.. In polymorphic case you have one model which can belong to multiple models polymorphically but here it is the inverse I have 2 models both belonging to one model... can you elaborate how can this be modeled using polymorphic association ?

Comment: but in this model a business has many discovery type.. the business will have one discovery type and a discovery type needs to have many business .. I want to have querries like this
for example

`DiscoverType.first.businesses`

this will tell me which business discovered us using 'Google'

and for each business or rep I will have something like

@business.discovery_type this will tell me how did this business discover use.

Comment: You're right - polymorphic association was the reverse relationship of the one you wanted.  I edited my answer.